# How To Initiate The (Redux Framework Builder) Generated Admin Folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I am trying to include the Redux Framework in my theme. I decided to try the online builder of Redux Framework: http://build.reduxframework.com/ to generate the necessary files for me.

**The builder of Redux provides two options:**

**(1).** To generate and export the admin folder.
**(2).** To generate and export a starter theme with the Redux settings.

I think i need option (1) since i have a theme already in my hands.

**The admin folder contains the following:**

**(1).** The Redux Builder generated (.Json) file.
**(2).** The admin folder itself - which contains the framework and extensions folders along with two (.php) files: **(*admin-init.php*)** and **(*options-init.php*)**.

The documentation of Redux Framework teaches us how to load the config file of the framework inside our theme. It does not inform us through what to do with the exported admin folder and how to use it in our theme - in case we chose to use the online builder.

**The online builder of Redux framework states the following:**

> Download just the admin folder portion. This will provide you with a
>   folder you can place in a theme or plugin and include
>   ~/admin/admin-init.php to initate it.

**Side note:** It is written as "**initate**" instead of "**initiate**". If any of the developers happen to read this question, it may be a nice thing to correct this small typing mistake.

**My Question:**

**(Q1).** How should i **initiate** the admin file? I couldn't find that in the documentation. Is it about copying its content to the (functions.php) file after fixing the directories? Or something else is required?

1. Include the Redux framework.
2. Copy the generated admin folder to your theme.
3. Copy the contents of admin-init.php to functions.php file of your theme.
4. Fix the directories names and files depending on your theme's structure.

**Is that right or i am missing something up there?**

Any clarifications, answers or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here. Good call on the spelling check.

Just include that file and that's it!   :)

Comment: It would be nice to see more video tutorials from your team. Great framework!

Comment: We're actually working on it! It will be coming shortly.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to initiate, i don't know if it's the best way or not

in my themes, i add :

`require get_template_directory() . '/admin/admin-init.php'; )`

in my function.php so i don't have to fix the directories files and names in redux admin folder depending on my themes.